# How to remove the data in XML and keep only some data?

Tags: java, regex

Below is my xml and I'm using `String.replaceAll` function to get only the "Unable to find the data". What regex can I use?

```
<errors>
    <error>
    <![CDATA[Unable to find data{}. Possible keys are ["A", "B", "C"]. Please verify your xml.]]>
    </error>
</errors>
```

Comment: Do not use regular expressions to parse XML.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-reg .

Answer (score 1):

using regex for xml is a mistake. You never know where comments or such will be placed in an xml document screwing up your regex. Use an xml parser.